# Merge_asof but only let the nearest merge on key

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to merge two data frames using the merge_asof method. However, when using this method I stumbled upon the issue that if I have a empty gap in any of my data then there will be issues with duplicate cells in the merged dataframe. For clarification, I two dataframes that look like this:

1.

```
index     Meter_Indication (km)     Fuel1 (l)
0         35493                     245
1         35975                     267
2         36000                     200
3         36303                     160
4         36567                     300
5         38653                     234
```

2. 

```
index     Meter_Indication (km)     Fuel2 (l)
0         35494                     300
1         35980                     203
2         36573                     323
3         38656                     233
```

These two dataframes contain data about refueling vehicles where the fuel column is refueled amount in liters and the Meter_Indication indicate how many km the car in total has driven (something that is impossible to become less over time, and is why it is a great key to merge on). However, as you can see there are less rows in df2 than in df1 which currently (in my case makes it so that the values merge on the nearest value. Like this:

3. (merged df)

```
index     Meter_Indication (km)     Fuel1 (l)     Fuel2(l)
0         35493                     245           300
1         35975                     267           203
2         36000                     200           203
3         36303                     160           323
4         36567                     300           323
5         38653                     234           233
```

As you can see there are duplicates of the value `203` and `323`. My goal is to instead of the dataframe containing all the 5 rows, instead excluding the ones that dont have a "nearest"-match. I want only the actually nearest to merge with the value. With other words my desired data frame is:

```
index     Meter_Indication (km)     Fuel1 (l)     Fuel2(l)
0         35493                     245           300
1         35975                     267           203
3         36567                     300           323
4         38653                     234           233
```

You can see here that the values that were not a "closest" match with another value were dropped.

I have tried looking for this everywhere but cant find anything to match my desired outcome.

My current code is:

```
    #READS PROVIDED DOCUMENTS.
    df1 = pd.read_excel(
        filepathname1, "CWA107 Event", na_values=["NA"], skiprows=1, usecols="A, B, C, D, E, F")
    df2 = pd.read_excel(
        filepathname2,
        na_values=["NA"],
        skiprows=1,
        usecols=["Fuel2 (l)", "Unnamed: 3", "Meter_Indication"],)

    # Drop NaN rows.
    df2.dropna(inplace=True)
    df1.dropna(inplace=True)

    #Filters out rows with the keywords listed in 'blacklist'.
    df1.rename(columns={"Bränslenivå (%)": "Bränsle"}, inplace=True)
    df1 = df1[~df1.Bränsle.isin(blacklist)]
    df1.rename(columns={"Bränsle": "Bränslenivå (%)"}, inplace=True)

    #Creates new column for the difference in fuellevel column.
    df1["Difference (%)"] = df1["Bränslenivå (%)"]
    df1["Difference (%)"] = df1.loc[:, "Bränslenivå (%)"].diff()

    # Renames time-column so that they match.
    df2.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 3": "Tid"}, inplace=True)

    # Drops rows where the difference is equal to 0.
    df1filt = df1[(df1["Difference (%)"] != 0)]

    # Converts time-column to only year, month and date.
    df1filt["Tid"] = pd.to_datetime(df1filt["Tid"]).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(str)

    df1filt.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

    #Renames the index column to "row" in order to later use the "row" column 
    df1filt.rename(columns={"index": "row"}, inplace=True)

    # Creates a new column for the difference in total driven kilometers (used for matching)
    df1filt["Match"] = df1filt["Vägmätare (km)"]
    df1filt["Match"] = df1filt.loc[:, "Vägmätare (km)"].diff()

    #Merges refuels that are previously seperated because of the timeintervals. For example when a refuel takes a lot of time and gets split into two different refuels.
    ROWRANGE = len(df1filt)+1
    thevalue = 0
    for currentrow in range(ROWRANGE-1):
        if df1filt.loc[currentrow, 'Difference (%)'] >= 0.0 and df1filt.loc[currentrow-1, 'Difference (%)'] <= 0:
            thevalue = 0
            thevalue += df1filt.loc[currentrow,'Difference (%)']
            df1filt.loc[currentrow,'Match'] = "SUMMED"
        if df1filt.loc[currentrow, 'Difference (%)'] >= 0.0 and df1filt.loc[currentrow-1, 'Difference (%)'] >= 0:
            thevalue += df1filt.loc[currentrow,'Difference (%)']
        if df1filt.loc[currentrow, 'Difference (%)'] <= 0.0 and df1filt.loc[currentrow-1, 'Difference (%)'] >= 0:
            df1filt.loc[currentrow-1,'Difference (%)'] = thevalue
            df1filt.loc[currentrow-1,'Match'] = "OFFICIAL"        
            thevalue = 0

    #Removes single "refuels" that are lower than 5
    df1filt = df1filt[(df1filt['Difference (%)'] > 5)]

    #Creates a new dataframe for the summed values 
    df1filt2 = df1filt[(df1filt['Match'] == "OFFICIAL")]

    #Creates a estimated refueled amount column for the automatic
    df1filt2["Fuel1 (l)"] = df1filt2["Difference (%)"]
    df1filt2["Fuel1 (l)"] = df1filt2.loc[:, "Difference (%)"]/100 *fuelcapacity

    #Renames total kilometer column so that the two documents can match
    df1filt2.rename(columns={"Vägmätare (km)": "Meter_Indication"}, inplace=True)

    #Filters out rows where refuel and kilometer = NaN (Manual)
    df2filt = df2[(df2['Fuel2 (l)'] != NaN) & (df2['Meter_Indication'] != NaN)]

    #Drops first row
    df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True)

    #Adds prefix for the time column so that they match (not used anymore because km is used to match)
    df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(str) 

    #Rounds numeric columns
    decimals = 0
    df2filt['Meter_Indication'] = pd.to_numeric(df2filt['Meter_Indication'],errors='coerce')
    df2filt['Fuel2 (l)'] = pd.to_numeric(df2filt['Fuel2 (l)'],errors='coerce')
    df2filt['Meter_Indication'] = df2filt['Meter_Indication'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))
    df2filt['Fuel2 (l)'] = df2filt['Fuel2 (l)'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))

    #Removes last number (makes the two excels matchable)
    df2filt['Meter_Indication'] //= 10
    df1filt2['Meter_Indication'] //= 10

    #Creates merged dataframe with the two
    merged_df = df1filt2.merge(df2filt, on='Meter_Indication')
```

Hopefully this was enough information! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your merged df contains `Meter_Indication (km)`  from `df1`, but your expected output contains `Meter_Indication (km)`  from `df2`. Is this a typo? It also seems you have swapped the fuel columns in the expected output, which makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: I am very sorry! This has now been fixed. @Anders Källmar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Assign new column to keep meter indication from df2
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.assign(meter_indication_2=df2['Meter_Indication (km)']), on='Meter_Indication (km)', direction='nearest')

# Calculate absolute difference
df['meter_indication_diff'] = df['Meter_Indication (km)'].sub(df['meter_indication_2']).abs()

# Sort values, drop duplicates (keep the ones with the smallest diff) and do some clean up
df = df.sort_values(by=['meter_indication_2', 'meter_indication_diff']).drop_duplicates(subset=['meter_indication_2']).sort_index().drop(['meter_indication_2', 'meter_indication_diff'], axis=1)

# Output

   Meter_Indication (km)  Fuel1 (l)  Fuel2 (l)
0                  35493        245        300
1                  35975        267        203
4                  36567        300        323
5                  38653        234        233
```

Comment: Getting ```pandas.errors.MergeError: Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('float64') and dtype('O'), both sides must have numeric dtype```. Im guessing ```pd.to_numeric``` on both the Meter-Indication columns.

Comment: converted dtypes to float and drop nan values. However, I am currently getting this error: 
```ValueError: right keys must be sorted```

Comment: Have you tried sorting df2 on the `Meter_Indication (km)`? For `merge_asof` to work the values have to be sorted.

Comment: Yes I tried changing it to: ```merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.sort_values('Meter_Indication (km)').assign(Meter_Indication (km)=df2['Meter_Indication (km)']), on='Meter_Indication (km)', direction='nearest')```

Comment: I have fixed the error by writing it as "  `merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df1filt2, df2filt.sort_values('Mätarställning').assign(Mätarställning2=df2filt['Mätarställning']), on='Mätarställning', direction='nearest')
    merged_df['Mätarställning_Diff'] = merged_df['Mätarställning'].sub(merged_df['Mätarställning2']).abs()
    merged_df.sort_values(by=['Mätarställning2', 'Mätarställning_Diff']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Mätarställning2']).sort_index().drop(['Mätarställning2', 'Mätarställning_Diff'], axis=1)` but it unfortunately doesnt do the job. There are still as many rows as before.

Comment: You're not assigning the last part to anything. When you say there still are as many rows as before, are you looking at `merge_df` or att the output of `merged_df.sort_values(by=['Mätarställning2', 'Mätarställning_Diff']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Mätarställning2']).sort_index().drop(['Mätarställning2', 'Mätarställning_Diff'], axis=1)`? I guess I should have assigned the last row to `df` for clarity. Will edit.